# How to checkbox record?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So on page1.html I keep track of checkboxes clicked:

```
var checked = [];
$('input[type=checkbox]').on("click", function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
     checked.push($(this).val());
    }
}
```

Eventually, the user can click on a submit button that takes them to page2.html. So if I had checkboxes for and "Apple", "Bannana" checked, the next page would know Apple and Banana are checked. However when the user clicks the back button...

On the page itself it apepars that "Apple" and "Banana" are checked... but when the user checks "Peach".... it appears that the checked array only contains "Peach" and not "Apple" and "Banana". Is there some syntax I could use to keep track of "Apple" and "Banana" such that when the user hits the back button and checks "Peach" the array "checked" could contain "Apple" "Banana" and "Peach"?

Comment: Have you tried using a change event instead, and trigger the change event on page load?

Comment: Web is stateless.. You cannot accomplish that without using either `session` or `localstorage` or `storing them in db`

Comment: @Sushanth up vote for you. Session is the best bet for what Rolando needs.

Comment: If you set a $cookie, in your javascript, this should work, as long as you do not close your browser window.

Comment: There's no need to track this on a click-by-click basis: just extract the data in `onsubmit`. Then you can store it to localStorage, or a cookie. Server-side storage (sessions) is probably not a good idea since the browser might not read the original page from there again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a big fan of browsers with the behavior you mention, but you might also want to consider checking the status of each checkbox when the page loads, e.g.

```
$(function() {
  var checked = [];

  function addToChecked() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      checked.push($(this).val());
    }
  }

  $("input:checkbox")
      .each(addToChecked)
      .on("click", addToChecked);
});
```

Note this code means that values can only be added to `checked`. You'll have to add logic to remove values if the corresponding checkboxes are unchecked.

Comment: I would save the checkbox value that is selected, to a cookie variable in the javascript, on click.

Comment: @blachawk I don't think the problem is with the values of the checkboxes or even whether they are checked. The problem is maintaining an accurate array of checked values. There should only be one canonical state of the checkboxes, and it sounds like here, that's the page itself, not a cookie or localStorage.